# does samsung galaxy ace support otg?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, root-access, samsung, samsung-galaxy-ace, usb-on-the-go

I currently own a Sony z1 and had not hqve any troubles with an otg storage device. But I coulndt make the same storage device this to work with my galaxy ace. ROOTED Version 2.3.6

I have so far scoured google for answers but have found no satisfactory info.

So id like to know if there is any kind of step/procedure the I can do to make it work?

Im a fan of keepong old stuff from trash unless they really stop working specially electronics. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, this isn't something you can turn on in the settings, it's a hardware issue.  The Galaxy Ace does not support OTG, so it's not possible to use it.